# Problema na Leitura de arquivo texto com StreamReader

Tags: c#

Possuo um aplicação que possui um form que quando carregado efetua a leitura de 
um arquivo texto, da primeira linha até a última, com `StreamReader`. O problema é que não consigo ler 2 vezes consecutivas este mesmo arquivo. A única maneira de ler o arquivo novamente é fechando todo o sistema e iniciando novamente. Na primeira leitura, ao final executo o fechamento da instância. Ex. `Instancia.Close()`. Porém fazendo uma depuração verifico que antes de executar o método Close a instância está com a mensagem:

```
EndOfStream = 'srv.EndOfStream' gerou uma exceção do tipo System.ObjectDisposedException'.
```

Continuo a executando, e fecho este formulário. Quando carrego novamente o form, pela segunda vez consecutiva, quando irá executar o `While` a instância já está como o mesmo erro e o `While` é encerrado indicando que já chegou no final do arquivo.

Como pode ser o final do arquivo, se teóricamente foi fechado ao final da primeira execução e quando carrego novamente a leitura deveria começar do ínicio sem maiores problemas.

Pode por favor me dar uma idéia do que ocorre?.

Obrigado.

Segue o código:

```
namespace TesteStreamReaderACBRSAT
{
    public partial class LeituraArquivo : Form
    {
        static string linha;

        static string ArquivoVendaIni = "C:\\SAT\\VENDA.INI";
        static string ArquivoEntrada = @"C:\SAT\ENT.TXT";

        static StreamReader srv = new StreamReader(ArquivoVendaIni);
        static StreamWriter swe = new StreamWriter(ArquivoEntrada, true);

        public LeituraArquivo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LeituraArquivo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LerArquivo();
        }

        public static void LerArquivo()
        {
            if (File.Exists(ArquivoVendaIni))
            {
                try
                {
                    while ((linha = srv.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        VerQualEmpresa();

                        GravarArquivo();
                    }

                    swe.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(" O arquivo " + arquivo + " não foi localizado");
            }
        }

        private static void GravarArquivo()
        {
            swe.WriteLine(linha);
        }

        private static void VerQualEmpresa()
        {
            if (true)  // Aqui se uma determinada condição for verdadeira deve-se ler algumas
                       // linhas do arquivo e depois a leitura continua no método LeituraArquivo()
            {
                while ((linha = srv.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    GravarArquivo();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sem colocar código é difícil de perceber o que pode estar a fazer mal

Comment: Isso poderá estar relacionado com a forma como está a abrir e fechar o _StreamReader_. O melhor será mesmo colocar o código que está a usar.

Comment: Concordo como os colegas. Irei providenciar a exibição do código.

Answer (score -1):

Sem saber ao certo qual o objetivo do método `VerQualEmpresa`, penso que o código mais correto seria:

```
namespace TesteStreamReaderACBRSAT
{
    public partial class LeituraArquivo : Form
    {
        string ArquivoVendaIni = @"C:\SAT\VENDA.INI";
        string ArquivoEntrada = @"C:\SAT\ENT.TXT";

        public LeituraArquivo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LeituraArquivo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LerArquivo();
        }

        public void LerArquivo()
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(ArquivoVendaIni))
                {
                    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ArquivoVendaIni))
                    {
                        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ArquivoEntrada, true))
                        {
                            VerQualEmpresa(sr, sw);

                            while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                                GravarArquivo(sw, sr.ReadLine());
                        }

                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
                else MessageBox.Show(" O arquivo " + arquivo + " não foi localizado");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void GravarArquivo(StreamWriter sw, string linha)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(linha);
        }

        private void VerQualEmpresa(StreamReader sr, StreamWriter sw)
        {
            // Aqui se uma determinada condição for verdadeira deve-se ler algumas
            // linhas do arquivo e depois a leitura continua no método LeituraArquivo()
            if (true)  
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                    GravarArquivo(sw, sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Claro que se ficar como está, após a execução do método `VerQualEmpresa` o `StreamReader` já chegou ao fim e não será lida mais nenhuma linha.

Talvez deva validar o que o código deverá efetivamente fazer...